# How to turn on warning on rm command?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, terminal, command, rm

I recently installed Ubuntu and find that when I delete things in terminal using

```
rm file
```

there is no warning asking me to confirm the step. I did not use the -f flag. It feels vulnerable to accidental deletion in this way.
I searched online and didn't find the reason for this. How can I turn on the warning?

Comment: the reason is that linux is assuming that you know what you are doing (btw: `del` in Windows command-prompt don't ask you either ... this is kindof the expected behavior for as long as I can remember using computers)

Comment: in case you are still wondering: the `-i` switch should ask you (if you really want) [see here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/urm.htm)

Comment: But in the man page of rm it still defines the -f option clearly. Btw the previous linux system I used will prompt a warning message. I guess it is dependent on the shell. But since they all use bash, why is there difference?

Answer (score 4):

Put `alias rm='rm -i'` in your `~/.bash_rc` or rc file of your shell. Then
`source ~/.bash_rc`.

It will start asking for confirmation and whenever you don't want this. Use one of the following

```
$\rm file
$command rm file
```

`\` escapes the `alias` and I like `\` better due to it's lesser typing

This explanation assumes that you are using `bash`. The name for rc file may differs based on your shell

Comment: Note that it's dangerous: when you move to a different machine/user without the alias, you can accidentally remove files. It's better to use a different name for the alias.

Comment: @Deleisha  Just wondering what does command stand for in $command rm file?

Comment: Oh, `command` is  shell builtin, Type `command` at prompt before using `rm`

Comment: where can I get a shirt that says,   "alias rm='rm -i'"?